# Prevent javascript hack script from executing

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, macros

I have a registration form to sign up which works fine. As part of abuse / bot prevention the registration page will show an antiscript check if you attempt to sign up another account from the same IP address within 3 hours of the last.

However I have managed to get hold of a script which is managing to get round this check. The script can be run with a macro extension to firefox on Windows. It uses the email.txt as a source for email addresses.

```
email="email.txt"
akun=new Array()
ID=new Array()

for(ns=1;ns<=2000;ns++){
iimPlay("CODE:"
+"\n"+"CMDLINE !DATASOURCE "+email
+"\n"+"SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1"
+"\n"+"SET !LOOP "+(ns)
+"\n"+"SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}")
akun[ns]=iimGetLastExtract();if(akun[ns]==""||akun[ns]=="undefined"||akun[ns]=="#eanf#")
{break}
ID[ns]=akun[ns].replace("@yahoo.com","")


i=iimPlay("CODE:"
+"\n"+"URL GOTO=http://www.website.com/signup"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT="+akun[ns]
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:confirm CONTENT="+akun[ns]
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT="+ID[ns]
+"\n"+"SET !ENCRYPTION NO"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=satan1234"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:confirm_password CONTENT=satan1234"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:referral CONTENT=52799"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:tos CONTENT=YES"
+"\n"+"pause"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:street-register ATTR=NAME:register&&VALUE:Play<SP>For<SP>Free<SP>→"
+"\n"+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Logout"
)
if(i!=1){break};
iimDisplay (ns)
}
```

Can anyone give a heads up as to how I can stop this script from working endlessly?

Thanks

Comment: How is it circumventing your check? Are the requests coming from the same IP address, then cancel the request (on the SERVER SIDE). If they are coming from different IP addresses, you might not be able to prevent it so easily.

Comment: All accounts created using this script originate from the same IP address.

Comment: If they are all coming from the same IP, then you are doing something wrong with your abuse prevention.

Answer (score 1):

Since all request do originate from the same IP address, please doa  server-side check with your logic. Somewhere you should store what requests have already been placed. Then check the server variable "remote address" against these values. Have they already placed a request the last 3 hours, then reject it and don't process it any further.

Don't rely on client-side scripts. And also don't rely on any values passed on by the client's request, as they can all be manipulated.